# Internet Explorer 11 Back Caching and TabProcGrowth

Tags: caching, navigation, registry, back, internet-explorer-11

I've stumbled upon the issue outlined here:

[Internet Explorer 11 Back Button Javascript Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274085/internet-explorer-11-back-button-javascript-behavior)

While experimenting with various approaches on how to resolve the issue I noticed that if the TabProcGrowth registry-key is set to a value of DWORD=0 then IE11 seizes to cache all those webpages I noticed it caching before the aforementioned registry tweak. However, even if something like this is true I can't find any documentation which explicitly mentions this side-effect of setting TabProcGrowth to zero. The thought of putting my money on such an approach makes me feel uneasy so I would like to ask if there's anyone that can verify my claim in a well-informed manner (docs etc).

Quick footnote: Yes ... I'm aware that this registry setting is not the best idea in the world performance-wise, but for the sake of argument let's assume I'm desperate because I have no control over the webpages or the web servers that deliver them, so pulling tricks with http headers is a no-go for me. However when it comes to the client's registry, that, I can tweak. This is why I'm asking.

Comment: For anyone interested I opened a ticket in 'IE's feedback' website:

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/905660/when-navigating-ie11-back-caching-feature-dramatically-changes-the-behaviour-of-the-underlying-iwebbrowser2-object

Comment: I can't get TabProcGrowth to take effect in ie11.  Is it just HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\TabProcGrowth still?

Comment: I stopped working on said project. I think we resorted to popping the developer tools (F12) to disable back-forward caching. Yeah, not pretty but it worked better than anything else.

Comment: thanks but I'm not actually trying to solve the same problem. I am trying to work out how to get ie11 to use a process per tab and your post was one of the only ones that explicitly mentions ie11 and that registry setting. There are several for older ie versions .  As far as you know that registry setting should work with ie11 and wasn't just for previous versions?

Comment: I don't remember to be frank but it shouldn't be hard to form conclusions on an experimental basis. I guess you have to try it out and see (unless I'm missing some prohibitive factor of course).