# IE 11 browser back button Detect

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

How do I detect the browsers back button is clicked in IE 11 browser. 
In IE <10 browsers we can achieve this functionality using the following:

`(window.event.clientX < 40 && window.event.clientY < 0)`.

Please share your thoughts.

Comment: you might want to check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274085/internet-explorer-11-back-button-javascript-behavior)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will detect the back button's click. The `/* Your code here! */` is whatever you want to do when the back button is clicked.

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function (event) {
    /* Your code here! */
}, false);
window.history.pushState({}, "", window.location.toString());
```

By default, clicking the back button will make it go back. To stop it, use `event.preventDefault()`. If you want to make it go back manually, just use `window.history.back()`.

This will only work in IE11. IE10 or older doesn't support the `history` API.

Comment: Is there a way to detect  browser close (X) event. I tried to use the popstate but it works only when the history changes. I did not find a solution to detect closing of a browser. Any help please.

Comment: You can't detect closing a browser. You CAN detect when your page is exited, though.